# antlr4 - Parser not working correctly when using tokens

Tags: parsing, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I created a very simple grammar to show the problem I encountered:

```
grammar Expr;
test: funcDecl;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
funcDecl:    funcHead ';';
funcHead:    type '*'? IDENTIFIER '(' formParList? ')';
formParList: ( 'void' |
               type '*'? IDENTIFIER ('[' ']')?
               (',' type '*'? IDENTIFIER ('[' ']')?)*
             );
type:        'void' | 'bool' | 'int';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitespace:     [ \t]+ -> skip;
LineComment:    '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
NEWLINE :       ('\r' '\n'? | '\n') -> skip;

IDENTIFIER:     CHARACTER (CHARACTER | DIGIT)*;

fragment
CHARACTER: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment
DIGIT:     [0-9];
```

The grammar above generates the following AST with this example code:

```
void Sieve(int n); // declaration
```

[image: AST]

This is what the grammar looks like after changing the `type` to a token (changing `type` to `TYPE`):

```
...
funcHead:    TYPE '*'? IDENTIFIER '(' formParList? ')';
...
TYPE:        'void' | 'bool' | 'int';
...
```

After doing so, I get the following error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'void' expecting TYPE
```

Why is that? As soon as I use a token for the type, the parser throws this error. But the `IDENTIFIER` token works regardless...

Comment: As I remember the longest first matching rule wins and 'void' is matched by TYPE and IDENTIFIIER. So is the definition of TYPE above IDENTIFIER?

Comment: True, that's what the parser is doing, but the `TYPE` is defined before `IDENTIFIER`. `TYPE` is defined on line 10, while `IDENTIFIER` is defined on line 18. (Basically I just renamed `type` to `TYPE` from my original code snippet)

Comment: Did you try it below IDENTIFIER?

Comment: Just did. Makes no difference whatsoever. :/ I mean, it does make sense to use a rule for the `type`, but I can't even assign a token to the `type` (bool, int, etc.).

Comment: Have you changed your formParList not to contain 'void'. Every Literal used in the parser section becomes an implicit Lexer Token with priority over the explicitly defined tokens.

Comment: Well, `void` is needed for syntax like `Sieve(void)`. Removing `void` worked. How would I fix that then? :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your formParList not to contain 'void'. Every Literal used in the parser section becomes an implicit Lexer Token with priority over the explicitly defined tokens.

If you need void in this position you can do something like this:

```
funcHead:    type '*'? IDENTIFIER '(' formParList? ')';
formParList: ( VOID |
           type '*'? IDENTIFIER ('[' ']')?
           (',' type '*'? IDENTIFIER ('[' ']')?)*
         );
type:        TYPE | VOID;

...

TYPE:        'bool' | 'int';
VOID:        'void';

...
```

Or you assign every type its own Lexer token, then the parser rule for type would look like: `type: VOID | BOOL | INT`. This is probably more convenient, if you have to interpret the AST later on.

Comment: This does not work as is, but it gave me some ideas on how to fix it (not yet implemented it though). Could you, however, add the answers you provided in the comments on my question, so that I can accept this?